# join does not work for me

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, listview

i am trying to get data from my database with entity framework and show in listview, i want to implement join in entity framework, but it returns null! i have data in my database.

my codes :

```
using (var context = new MyEntities())
        {
            IEnumerable<Core_Permissions> MyList = (from p in context.Core_Permissions
                 from rp in context.Core_RolePermissions
                 where p.PermissionID == rp.PermissionID
                 where rp.RoleID == roleid
                 select p).ToList();
            lvGranted.DataSource = MyList;
            lvGranted.DataBind();

        }
```

or :

```
(from p in context.Core_Permissions 
    join rp in context.Core_RolePermissions
    on p.PermissionID equals rp.PermissionID select rp).ToList();
```

HTML :

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvGranted" runat="server" >
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable" style="min-height: 200px;width: 300px;border: 1px solid black;">
        <li id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></li>
    </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" >
            <label id='<%#Eval("PermissionID") %>'><%#Eval("RoleID") %></label>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

in other hand my jon query returns null! but i have data in my database.

Comment: Use Profiler and see the generated query or post the generated query here.

Comment: sorry but how should i use Profiler ?

Comment: exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[PermissionID] AS [PermissionID], 
[Extent1].[PermissionGroupID] AS [PermissionGroupID], 
[Extent1].[PermissionName] AS [PermissionName], 
[Extent1].[PermissionTitle] AS [PermissionTitle]
FROM  [dbo].[Core_Permissions] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Core_RolePermissions] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[PermissionID] = [Extent2].[PermissionID]
WHERE [Extent2].[RoleID] = @p__linq__14',N'@p__linq__14 int',@p__linq__14=1

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. You asked how to use Profiler -

[SQL SERVER – Introduction to SQL Server 2008 Profiler](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/03/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-2008-profiler-2/)

[image]

Comment: My wrong bro, i have tow table that are same, and in one i have data and in another i dont have data in Core_RolePermissions now it returns my data. thank you very much

Comment: @KamranSadin I'm glad that you figure out. If this answered your question, please mark it as **Answer**.